Resolve conflicting python package requirements (pandas-ai and python-pptx specifically)
When trying to install both, I get
#0 29.78 ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 40) and -r requirements.txt (line 52) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
#0 29.78 
#0 29.78 The conflict is caused by:
#0 29.78     pandasai 2.2.12 depends on pillow<11.0.0 and >=10.1.0
#0 29.78     python-pptx 0.6.22 depends on Pillow<=9.5.0 and >=3.3.2

I’m puzzled as to how I can resolve this if the earliest pillow version pandas-ai supports is 10.1.0, and the latest python-pttx supports is 9.5.0. Both packages are at their latest version as of posting.
I’m now installing pandas-ai after installing from requirements.txt, and it kind of works, but I’m not sure that’s a sound approach.

"the earliest pillow version pandas-ai supports is 10.1.0, and the latest python-pttx supports is 9.5.0." I'm sure that's impossible to resolve. One of the packages must be rewritten to support a different version of Pillow. IMO python-pttx should support later version of Pillow.
